# Datatable weird display behavior

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Given this jsf Code

```
<p:dataTable id="dt1" var="tVar" value="#{regelBean.queriedElements}" scrollable="true"
   style="width: 30%; background-color: #F44">
     <p:column style="background-color: #4F4; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;" headerText="Regeltext">
        <h:outputText value="#{tVar.regelTxt}"/>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

where regelTxt is

```
AAB = 100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000006661000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000066610000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000666 AND
AA_depr_DB = 1
```

why is there a border of 17px on my datatable and no black border in the header?
[image: halp]

I tried every HTML style element from overflow, text-wrap, white-space to word-wrap. Nothing gives me what I want (plus it seems I HAVE to use `scrollable="true"`)

I want it to look like this (mad paint skills were applied) :

[image: mad paint skeelz solution1]

or like this:

[image: solution2]

How? Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I think that by default p:dataTable has its own style class'Check this using inspect tool in your browser', so you can add attribute of 'styleClass' to p:dataTable and give it a specified class of your own css.

Comment: I found out that `scrollWidth="101%"` partly solves the problem, although it seems like a dirty hack and I have no real idea why this is working. But still, I need `scrollable="true"` which I dont want.